# Developing a chart with auto-scaling with first of each month

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am using excel-vba tool and trying to customize it as per below -

I have the below linked chart.

All the characteristics (Color, Bars, …) are good to go. (The user enters dates in another table.) But: the horizontal axis should start on the first of each month.

This Template should fit for all kind of projects – no matter if it’s a 6 month time frame or 3 years.

There should be the same amount of “marks” (means an interval of “every 2 months” wouldn’t work at all, because for an 3 years project, this would black out the whole chart).

*Note: not each each month! Each shown month.*

The chart can be refreshed every time by a button, so it won't have to run and check for changes all the time.

[image: raw Chart without axis set to first each month]

**I’m relatively new to “the art of the vba” and don’t know how to get there at all. Can you help me out?**

Comment: Depending on the chart type, the simple way is to format the axis (link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/display-or-change-dates-on-a-category-axis-d5a8146b-d457-43d1-8602-c1d23c96d650).  I haven't seen that chart type though (nice work, btw) so presumably, your code will need some sort of "format axis" line that allows you to set the type to Date.

Comment: Basically it's a bar chart with multiple bars. One transperent 100%, one green, one red, one transperent green, and one gray itsself - each one with with gray borders,

I'll try something with your idea - but I'm not that optimistic #newby

Thanks so nevertheless!

Comment: Unfortunately, even with the instructions in the link, I can't figure out how to make the dates behave the way you want.  If I figure it out, I'll post a formal answer.  Also, can you post your code for the chart?  That may help.

Comment: My chart is created without macro/vba. can i read it's code anywhere?

Comment: No...if you created it manually, then there is no code.  You might want to remove the VBA and Excel-VBA tags as well as the references to -VBA in your question.

Comment: I'm sure, the only possible solution will be with vba! for this reason i won't remove them as they represent my only way to the solution.  But the code for the chart is irrelevant. The solution would be the same as if you would have a simple bar chart.   -- but i don't know any possible way :(

Comment: Fair enough; just a recommendation: the respondents on SO will generally want to see your attempt at code first.  So, if you want help with a vba solution, post some code.

Comment: As to Sam's remark: indeed, the chances are high that your question will be closed as too broad if you haven't done anything at all. You might try recording a macro when creating the chart - that will give everyone a starting point.

Comment: I will restart a new topic with the main probelm, thanks for all the responses. This one can be kept on hold or get deleted. Thanks so much anyway!